# Passing value from a ListView to another activity

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to get data to pass from a list view to the activity it opens. However when clicking on the listView it crashes my app.

I can't see what's wrong with my code and looking at numerous other examples I'm unsure what is going wrong. The listView was working fine before I started trying to pass data through.

```
public class SuitableFarmerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        private String[] farmerArray = {"John Smith, 28 days, £2800", "Ben Shaw, 31 days, £2400", "Tom Freer, 32 days, £3400", "Sam Jones, 24 days, £3600"};

        private ListView farmerListView;
        private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_suitable_farmer);

            farmerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.farmerList);

            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, farmerArray);
            farmerListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            farmerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                        long id) {

                    Object obj = farmerListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                    String value= obj.toString();
                    Intent confirm = new Intent(SuitableFarmerActivity.this, ConfirmOrderActivity.class);
                    confirm.putExtra("value", value);

                    startActivity(confirm);

                }
            });
        }

}
```

Above is my activity code.

Below is the code I'm using to try and retrieve the data in the next activity.

```
  Bundle recdData = getIntent().getExtras();
    String myVal = recdData.getString("value");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirm_order);

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setText(myVal);
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as I posted the question I found the answer.

For anyone else that has this issue I fixed it by moving where I was retrieving the data in my second activity to inside the onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirm_order);
    Bundle recdData = getIntent().getExtras();
    String myVal = recdData.getString("value");

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    textView.setText(myVal); }
```

Hope this helps anyone having this issue.

Comment: and how do you refer and post the items on the second activity? let's say you pass the name of an animal..how do you refer to the name on the second activity?

Answer (score 1):

Write down the following code inside the oncreate method not outside the oncreate .

```
 Bundle recdData = getIntent().getExtras();
String myVal = recdData.getString("value");
```